# DOM Parser not able to parse large xml file

Tags: java, xml, xpath, domparser

I am trying to parse a large xml file using DOM Parser and Xpath, but it seems like my code breaks as it's a large xml file (60000 lines). When I try and print the xml, it starts printing from the middle of the xml. Any ideas how I can avoid this?

Regards

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder =  builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(file);
        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        disclaimer = xPath.compile(disclaimerPath + File.separator + "title").evaluate(xmlDocument);

            TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            transformer.transform(new DOMSource(xmlDocument), new StreamResult(writer));

            System.out.println(writer.getBuffer().toString().replaceAll("\n|\r", ""));
```

Comment: Do you only use your console for reference? Could it be, that your console simply keeps track of about 30000 lines. To you it would seem as only the last 30000lines were parsed, but instead not every line was displayed. How about writing your results down in a txt. file, or introduce a counter that counts the lines of your document.

Comment: @TomWellbrock : Good Idea. I should try that